# Sending reminder in Outlook for Mac

Tags: microsoft-outlook, macos-catalina, outlook-web-access

I was seeking functionality wherein I can send reminders to a couple of folks on specific days at a specific time. I'd want to avoid sending a meeting invite of zero duration since...well...it's not a meeting! The steps shared [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1785-outlook-send-email-with-reminder.html) don't appear to be applicable to the UI on **Outlook for Mac/OWA** and I couldn't figure out any other option. Any suggestions on whether this functionality exists on Mac/OWA platforms and if yes, how do we go about it?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, in Outlook for Mac/OWA, I'm afraid there is no other feasible way besides creating regular meetings to remind other users. Or you could try to find some third-party add-ins to help your achieve that.

By the way, if you could use Outlook for Windows, [assigning tasks with reminders to other users](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/assign-and-track-tasks-cdc1a3de-4e4c-44f6-8921-77a8cd43e971) regularly should be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the response but the suggestions on the link you shared inhibit sharing the tasks with folks on Mac/OWA: *Tasks assigned from Outlook for Windows must be accepted or declined using the Outlook for Windows application. This experience is not supported in Outlook on the web.* That won't be possible since the other folks too are on MAC/OWA.

Comment: That's ture. So as mentioned above, I'm afraid there is no other feasible way besides creating regular meetings to remind other users.